# How to change the user attributes(with the necessary human) in ActiveDirectory from SharePoint 2010?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, authentication, active-directory

To retrieve data from ActiveDirectory I used the following code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
 (
            var currentDirectory = new DirectoryEntry(domainAddress);
));
```

But changing a property's value and attempt to update the values in ActiveDirectory (function `CommitChanges()`) generates `System.UnauthorizedAccessException Message = Access is denid`, because code execution carried out under the account NetworkService.
I tried to use the following code to run from the current user:

```
using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate ())
{
             DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(domainAddress);
             ...
}
```

To run code from the current user, but continued use is generated DirectoryServicesCOMException, while user authentication is a protocol NTML. Prompt please, how is it possible to change the attributes of users in ActiveDirectory from the current user without requiring a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RunWithElevatedPrivileges` uses the identity of IIS application pool in which SharePoint is running. If you have not specified an Active Directory account, but it is configured to work under the built-in Network Service account, you will get this message.